# Python - String and int variable concat followed by value substitution

Tags: python

I have a list of variables in Python with below values.

I am trying to print the values of these variables in the following manner, but this is unsuccessful. Can someone please help with a solution ?

```
a1=1
a2=2
a3=3
for i in range(1,4):
  temp="a"+str(i)
  print(temp)
```

I want the output in 'temp' print the values(viz) 1,2,3 whereas the output seen are the variables (viz) a1,a2,a3

Comment: Even though the dupe target says you want a dictionary, in your case, you likely want a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:-

```
a1=1
a2=2
a3=3
for i in range(1,4):
  temp="a"+str(i)
  print locals()[temp]
```